# What is an example of an orbifold which is not a topological manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, orbifolds

In Thurston's book *The Geometry and Topology of Three-Manifolds* it is proven that the underlying space of a two-dimensional orbifold is always a topological surface.

Are there any easy examples of higher dimensional orbifolds whose underlying spaces are not topological manifolds?

Comment: The quotient of $\mathbb R^3$ by the order $2$ group generated by $-id$ is an open cone over $RP^2$. It is contractible, and if it were a 3-manifold, then removing a point would not change its fundamental group, which is trivial. Removing the cone point gives a non-simply-connected space.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out that, even in dimension 1 (and 2), the underlying topological space of a *closed* orbifold can be a manifold *with boundary*.  For instance, the closed interval $[0,1]$ with both endpoints labelled $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is a *closed* 1-dimensional orbifold, since it's double covered by the circle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is quite easy to give an example in real dimension $4$.

In fact, it was shown by D. Mumford in the paper

[**The topology of normal singularities of an algebraic surface and a criterion for simplicity**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=153682), *Inst. Hautes Etudes Sci. Publ. Math.* (1961), no. 9, 5 - 
22

that a normal algebraic surface over $\mathbb{C}$, whose underlying topological space (in the usual topology) is a topological manifold, must be nonsingular.

Now take the orbifold $X:=\mathbb{C}^2/G$, where $G$ is the group of order $2$ whose generator $\xi$ acts as $\xi \cdot (x, \, y) = (-x, \, -y)$.

The $G$-invariant subalgebra is generated by $A:=x^2, \, B=xy, \, C:=y^2$, so the underlying algebraic surface $X$ is isomorphic to the affine quadric cone $\{B^2-AC=0 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^3$, which has a $A_1$-singularity at its vertex. Such a singularity is normal, because it is a codimension two hypersurface singularity.

Then $X$ cannot be a topological manifold  by Mumford's result mentioned above.

Comment: Is my intuition correct that the boundary of any small neighborhood of the singular point would have a nontrivial fundamental group, and this should not happen for topological manifolds? Or am I being naive here?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Mumford strategy of proof is precisely based on the analysis of the local fundamental group of the singularity.

Comment: very small neighborhood *minus the singular point itself*. Every orbifold is locally contractible.

Comment: @YCor Thank you, this makes more sense than trying to somehow think of the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

To give a compact version of Igor's example, consider the antipodal map in the tangent space of a round 3-sphere at a point.  This extends to an isometry of the 3-sphere with a pair of fixed points.  The quotient by the isometry is a manifold with two conical singularities which is not homeomorphic to a topological 3-manifold.

Comment: Or just the quotient of a 3-ball by the antipodal map will work.